# How to contruct a row literal having only one of the row's columns?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have (In Postgres v12) a function which takes a row as an argument and returns a count from a referenced table.
Simplified example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.my_count(my public.mytable) RETURNS bigint
  LANGUAGE sql STABLE
  AS $$
    SELECT count(id) FROM public.another_table WHERE another_table.my = 'foo' AND another_table.my_id=my.id;
  $$;
```

The signature of the function is fixed by external requirements, it is being called by a middleware.

Now I want to use this function by itself, hopefully without having to construct an entire '()' row literal for the `mytable` row that is the argument, since I only need the `.id` from it, not the other columns.

```
SELECT my_count('(123,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,)');
```

actually works. But it looks fugly. Is there a better way?

Comment: Unrelated, but: if `id` is defined as not null, then `count(*)` will actually be slightly faster than `count(id)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take a detour using JSON:

```
select my_count(json_populate_record(null::public.mytable, '{"id": 123}'));
```

Comment: Ah. Clever! Just what the doctor ordered. (Edited for syntax :-) )